# I'm running into some odd .NET behavior, is there something I may be missing?

Tags: c#, .net

I have an application written for work (Sorry, proprietary code, so I can't share much of it.) Written with VS2015 C# on Win7. It operated fine on my PC, (as it should,) but when it's deployed, not all the other machines react properly.

It started with writing it for .NET 4.5.2, it was later moved to .NET 4.6.2 but it still suffers the same issues. It would install and start to run, but immediately issue a Startup Exception on some machines, while others would have no problems.

As I stated, it doesn't happen on every machine installed to. (current images on the machines has either .NET 4.6.2 or 4.7) My work around so far has been to, after uninstalling the currently installed version, go all the way back to 4.5 and incrementally install each new version,  which apparently clears the problem. (I usually make sure it's 4.7 or 4.7.1 when I'm finished.) Of course this eats time (about an hour.)

So, what I need is to better understand why some machines and not others are effected. More importantly, what areas should I focus on to find where the fault is that may be causing the issue. That way there, I can make it easier for others to either fix or better yet, not need to fix, the install.

The method throwing the Object reference not set to an instance of an object exception is:

```
// ORIGINAL SOURCE: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/63147/Handling-database-connections-more-easily
// ORIGINAL ARTICLE: Handling database connections more easily
// ORIGINAL AUTHOR: Alaric Dailey
//       PUBLISHED: 2011/07/11
//
// LICENSE: CPOL 1.02 -  http://www.codeproject.com/info/cpol10.aspx
private string QuoteSuffix
{
    get
    {
        // Create it if it doesn't already exist
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(quotePrefix))
        {
            quoteSuffix = CommandBuilder.QuoteSuffix;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(quoteSuffix))
                quoteSuffix = "\"";
            quoteSuffix = quoteSuffix.Trim();
        }
        // send it out
        return (quoteSuffix);
    }
}
```

I assume that for some reason CommandBuilder isn't being initialized properly on the installs that fail to run. (The code is compiled as part of the build, not as a library or DLL)

Comment: You've got a reference to `quotePrefix` in the `if` line that I think is supposed to be `quoteSuffix`.

Comment: If you're getting an null reference exception, then it shouldn't have anything to do with your .Net versioning.

Comment: Oy! I missed that. Now I feel silly over such a simple mistake.

Comment: @gilliduck. As to the exception and the .Net versioning... that's what I was finding odd as it wasn't constantly happening, and the exception went away doing the version updates incrementally. I'll know more later as the new version propagates to the install base and new users, but I think Adam V spotted my error that sometimes we all make (and the extra pair, or more, of eyes see.)